# How to get only required error message and not invalid Email message if Email is empty . YUP

Tags: javascript, yup

I am validating data that is coming from API to count progress of Form. If all fields are empty that means progress is 0. I am facing the problem when I get empty `email` field. yup throw 2 errors of `email` field. `email is required` & `invalid Email address`. Due to this my calculation is getting wrong. I just want to get `email is require` error message if `email` is empty and `invalid Email address` if `emeil` field is not empty.

Below is my code

```
let obj = { tradingName: "", phone: "", email: "", address: "" };


let schema = Yup.object({
  tradingName: Yup.string().required("Trading Name is required"),
  phone: Yup.string().required("phone is required"),
  email: Yup.string()
    .matches(
      /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
      "Invalid email address"
    )
    .required("Email is Required"),
  address: Yup.string().required("address is required")
});
schema
  .validate(obj, { abortEarly: false })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err.errors));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if condition inside [`.when`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schemawhenkeys-string--string-builder-object--values-any-schema--schema-schema)

```
let schema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string()
    .when("email", (value, schema) => {
      if (value?.length > 0) {
        return Yup.string().matches(
          /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
          "Invalid email address"
        );
      } else {
        return Yup.string().required("email is required");
      }
    })
}, ["email", "email"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think just swapping places in validation should work

```
email: Yup
    .string()
    .required('Email is Required')
    .matches(/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i, 'Invalid email 
    address'),
```